# Error in Sqoop data to sqlite

Tags: sqlite, hadoop, sqoop

I am not able to `sqoop` data from Hadoop cluster to another EC2 server having SqLite db, I am using following command:

```
sqoop export -D default-character-set=utf8 \
             --connect "jdbc:sqlite://ip_adresss/home/ec2-user/testLocaldb.db" \
             --username user_name \
             --password **** \
             --direct \
             --export-dir hdfs_path \
             --input-fields-terminated-by '|' \
             --table  table_name
```

Error:

```
ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Got error creating database manager:
  java.io.IOException: No manager for connect string:
  jdbc:sqlite://ip_adress/home/ec2-user/testLocaldb.db
```

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite isn't exposed over a network protocol, so specifying a network address to a database isn't possible.

You would need to

1. Add sqlite JDBC driver to the sqoop classpath
2. Export to the local filesystem
3. Copy that sqlite file to your external server
4. Merge tables between two sqlite files

Alternatively, you can use Amazon RDS or Redshift to give yourself a proper networked database that Sqoop prefers